# Retrieve Access Token within a AAD secured Azure Web App

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Angular4 Application hosted in an Azure Web App and a .NET core Web API hosted in an Azure API App.

The API is secured with Azure Active Directory. Currently I use ng2-adal to aquire an access token which I inject to the headers to perform my API calls.

Now I try to remove the ng2-adal module and secure my Web App with the **Authentication / Authorization** feature using the *same* ClientId (like the API). When I browse to my website I get redirected to the AAD login and after I successfully login, I get redirected to my site. Now I wan't to call the API (that is secured with the same ClientId) within my Web App but can't find a way to retrieve the token.

Is there a way to **retrieve the access token within my Angular App** in this scenario?
It looks like the token is stored encrypted within the AppServiceAuthSession Cookie:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the scenario, but you should have the necessary token in the reply url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#single-page-application-spa

Comment: @Sentinel Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the example you are referencing is using adal.js.

Comment: I don't think it is referencing any library at all, it's just saying that the token is in the reply url.

Comment: Anyhow, I can't find a token within the reply url.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `AppServiceAuthSession` is cookie which is different than a **token**. In this scenario, you need to modify the config of Azure app to make it acquire the access_token for the web API.

We can use the [Resource Explore](https://resources.azure.com/) to modify the settings like below:

1 . locate the angular web app

2 . locate the config->authsettings(resource is the clientId of Azure app which used to protect your apps)

```
"additionalLoginParams": [
  "response_type=code id_token",
  "resource=3fa9607b-63cc-4050-82b7-91e44ff1df38"
],
```

3. config the redirect_uri for Azure app like below:
    `https://appfei.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`

Then after you login in the angular app, you can get the **access_token** via the endpoint:
`https://appfei.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me`

[image]

Then we need to protect the web API using the **Advanced Azure Active Settings** like figure below to enable the access_token could call the web API:
[image]

Comment: Do you know whether its possible to apply this to an AAD B2C (just for the AAD with local accounts that is created with the B2C, No other social providers)

Comment: Based on my understanding, the Azure AD B2C extends the standard OAuth 2.0 flows to do more than simple authentication and authorization. It should also support in this scenario. More detail you can refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code#3-use-the-token).

Comment: I can get the token when I browse to the URL, but when I try and call it from my app service, I get 401 unauthorised? this is after I've logged in obviously

Answer (score 6):

I've been working on this for a week. 
So, I'd like to share how I got it.

I was able to have authentication for my app using AAD.

I have AppServiceAuthSession in my cookies storage.

Then on my application, I called the auth/me API.

https://yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me

So, it's like:

```
this.$http
  .get('https://yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me').then(response => {
    console.log(".auth/me", response)
  }, err => {
    console.log("Error: ", err)
  })
```

I'm actually using Vue. calling your HTTP might be different. 
And that's it.

I basically called the auth/me API to retrieve the information I needed.

P.S. You need to be authenticated of course.

Comment: How did you avoid this returning 401 unauthorised? I've done similar code in c# and it is throwing me that error even after being logged in and confirming via the ./me endpoint that I can see the token

Comment: Hi! Can you add more details please. A screenshot would be better. Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out, the issue was the instructions are misleading, you do not get auth token straight away, you have to exchange an id token for it

Answer (score -1):

found this solution:

just need to add your app url on 
Authentication / Authorization-> ALLOWED EXTERNAL REDIRECT URLS

so the webapi will automatically accept those cookies.

ps: make sure your ajax request is passing those cookies on it.