# Accessing token for current session / user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I have secured an azurewebsites domain with AAD authentication

I've navigated to the home page, logged in to the B2C account, and can access the contents of the Azure website - API, Views

What I'm puzzled about is every time I've done this before, it's been from an MSAL or ADAL library inside a Xamarin app. I've then known how to retrieve and use the token

Since I've just logged into the site and am browsing it, if I want to write some code to interact with the back end using tokens, how do I start to write code to access the current token? Is it saved somewhere when I log into the app?

UPDATE to this question: I decided to see what would happen by calling AcquireTokenSilentAsync and it responds with "no token was found in the cache."

I don't want the user to have to log in again after signing in, so how can I get a token I can use from that initial sign in please?

Comment: The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088339/retrieve-access-token-within-a-aad-secured-azure-web-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your server code, the provider-specific tokens are injected into the request header, so you can easily access them. Refer to the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#retrieve-tokens-in-app-code).

For example, to get the access token in your code.

```
string accessToken = this.Request.Headers["X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN"];
```

Answer (score 0):

So, MSAL doesn't store its cache unless you provide the via for it to do so. There are 3 common token cache providers:

- In memory
- Session
- Database

I would suggest you to check this project for cache implementation ideas:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web/Client/TokenCacheProviders . 
If you dont want to use any of these, you would retrieve the cached token using `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` if your `PublicClientApplication` is a singleton object.

About asking the user to login every time you need the token, this is a no no. The user needs to login only once and then MSAL will do its job silently.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, I'm not triggering MSAL in code - I have done, so I know how it works, but this is a new one for me, where I want to build a web app, and by default when you navigate to the azurewebsites domain it will make you log in - so my question is does that result in a cookie I can then use the ADAL library to read?