# Azure B2C - 401 unauthorised trying to read id_token in code after logging in

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to use the token granted by a secured AAD domain when using my web app

I followed the advice on this link: [Retrieve Access Token within a AAD secured Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088339/retrieve-access-token-within-a-aad-secured-azure-web-app)

I have managed to get as far as logging in and verifying the ./me URL correctly shows me my token

However when I try and call same token in code I get 401 unauthorised

I have been using the Resource Explorer to configure the additionalLoginParams and have tried to put the app ID as well as the graph URL but nothing has solved the problem

```
    async public Task<string> GetToken()

    {

        HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();


        string _token = "";

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("https://alfreton.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        ReadUserToken readUserToken = new ReadUserToken();

        readUserToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadUserToken>(responseBody);

        _token = readUserToken.id_token;

        return _token;


    }
}
```

}

EDIT Following the advice below the code now looks like this but I am still getting an Unauthorized error messsage

```
    async public Task<string> GetToken()

    {

        HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();


        string _token = "";

        string accessToken = this.Request.Headers["X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN"];

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("https://alfreton.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        ReadUserToken readUserToken = new ReadUserToken();

        readUserToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadUserToken>(responseBody);

        _token = readUserToken.id_token;


        return _token;


    }
```

When I read through the headers, I find there is X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN - can I use that to get an access token?

Comment: I think the URL expects the authentication cookie to be passed in the request. That would explain the 401.

Comment: Please can you review the updated code above and let me know if it looks right? Am still getting an error but if the code is right the error must be elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out, what I needed to do is get X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN from the Request Headers after logging in then pass that in as the Bearer and that in turn got me a X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN which I can use for accessing the API

Thanks loads!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @juunas, the URL expects the authentication cookie to be passed in the request when you aceess ./me URL.

The provider-specific tokens are injected into the request header, so you can easily access them. Your provider is AAD, so it should be

```
string accessToken = this.Request.Headers["X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN"];
```

Comment: Please can you review the updated code above and let me know if it looks right? Am still getting an error but if the code is right the error must be elsewhere?