# How to set AppServiceAuthSession cookie for azure app service manually/programmatically?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, cypress

**tl;dr**

I am trying to add cypress test for SPA but login does not work. Need help to set "AppServiceAuthSession" cookie.

**Details**

My single page application(SPA) is secured with Azure AD provider and uses authentication feature of Azure app service. When I login with credentials, app service responds with certain set-cookie headers which includes "AppServiceAuthSession". Once this cookie is added, application does not requires login on refresh.
As EasyAuth enabled, there is no custom code required and Azure app service handles authentication.
Cypress does not supports/recommends auto redirects. Logging in user prior to accessing SPA avoids redirects. As application does not have any custom code for login, MSAL and ADAL are not added to app which leverage browser localstorage to set tokens. There are two solutions I can think of:

1. Change authentication approach and use custom MSAL setup
2. Set "AppServiceAuthSession" cookie

Option 1 requires production code changes for cypress test which I believe is not recommended.
So need help to set "AppServiceAuthSession" cookie via cypress test.

I do not find any documentation around "AppServiceAuthSession" cookie, how to get it.
I tried [this](https://www.sourceallies.com/2020/02/cypress-in-azure/) solution but its not working, probably it requires ADAL setup in application.

Answer (score -1):

*The `AppServiceAuthSession` is cookie which differs to **token**, so modify the configuration of Azure app to fetch from the   access_token.*

*Locate the configuration->authsettings(resource is the clientId of Azure app which used to protect your apps)*

```json
"additionalLoginParams": [
  "response_type=code id_token",
  "resource=9hj2797f-29xf-4405-96x4-29g11hk4ce94"
],
```

*And config the redirect_uri for Azure app like "AzureUrl + /login/aad/callback"*

[image]

[image]

*And you can fetch the **access_token** from the endpoint url.*

**For more information on authentication and token check this* [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-vs-authorization#single-page-application-spa) and [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#3-use-the-token)

Comment: I am aware of `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie is different than accessToken. Are you saying after your suggested changes `accessToken` will get that cookie value?

Comment: yes, from the access token you will get value.

Comment: I do not see those two values are matching. Is there a way to get  `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie using accessToken or idToken as I have a way to get these two values with auth flows. @RajeshM

Comment: For more information, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088339/retrieve-access-token-within-a-aad-secured-azure-web-app)

Comment: May I request to read question description again? 


I want to setup `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie before accessing SPA home page for cypress test user as cypress does not allow redirects. If I go with standard flow, AAD login redirects are ought to happen and I want to avoid that for cypress test execution only.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.